# Significant figures in 3000.00

Tags: real-numbers

This is a dumb question but it came to my mind and I got shocked .

If $67.010$ have 4 significant figures because I count the 3rd decimal place into it , then how many significant figures has $3000.00$ has ? Am I right to say 6 ?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @user307640 The extra zeroes are to indicate precision. If you had something like $5000.00$, then the margin of error would be from $4999.995$ to $5000.005$, but if it was $5000$, then it would be from $4999.5$ to $5000.5$.

Comment: No, $67.010$ has five significant figures.

Comment: Ahh! I should really delete mine, since it's pointless having two identical comments. Well played good sir :P

Comment: @SamT: no problem, you are my guest.

Answer (score 1):

Trailing zeroes in the fractional part are indeed used to indicate that they are significant. And the most significant position is obviously the leftmost.

As far as I know, we have no equivalent notation when the least significant digit is in the integer part. In such a case, we have to switch to scientific notation, like

$$300,000=3.000\cdot10^5$$ for four significant digits.

Comment: @Moo: oops, no I meant $3.000\cdot10^5$. Now fixed.